# How to switch an Activity after a time interval when the user can navigate back to it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, timer, countdown

I have two activities; one is `IntermediateActivity`, and one is the `ButtonPress` activity. The `IntermediateActivity` has a 5-second timer. After the timer is over, the `ButtonPress` activity is opened, in which the user has to press a button placed in a random position on the screen within a time period (2 seconds for now), then I start an intent that opens the the `IntermediateActivity` again if the user is able to press the button or the time runs out.

What is happening is that for the runs of `ButtonPress`, the `IntermediateActivity` keeps opening up on its own and sometimes, the timer on the `IntermediateActivity` isn't complete but the `ButtonPress` activity gets launched. Adding a timer in `ButtonPress` resulted in a very erratic behaviour for both the activities.

Here's how I call the intent for `IntermediateActivity` in the `ButtonPress` Activity according to the timer and the user's action:

```
public class ButtonPress extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button button;
    private DisplayMetrics displaymetrics;
    private RelativeLayout loOPenArea;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button_press);

        button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        button.setClickable(true);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(ButtonPress.this, IntermediateActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);


        // Wait until the first layout to get button size and placement to compute x/y placement range.
        button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                button.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                // Capture width and x/y placement ranges here
                final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
                displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                loOPenArea = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.open_area_press);

                // Button will have a horizontal margin from zero to the width of its parent less
                // the width of the button less the initial left side of the button which is likely
                // to be the initial margin.
                int buttonMaxXMargin = loOPenArea.getWidth() - button.getWidth() - button.getLeft();
                // Similar for the vertical placement.
                int buttonMaxYMargin = loOPenArea.getHeight() - button.getHeight() - button.getTop();

                int leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(buttonMaxXMargin);
                int topMargin = new Random().nextInt(buttonMaxYMargin);

                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
                p.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);

                button.setLayoutParams(p);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.my_button:
                i = new Intent(ButtonPress.this, IntermediateActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }



}
```

I tried multiple things like using the `finish()` function and adding this line `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` in the manifest file but it's still not working.

Comment: try to make use of xml and use visibility for button. Make it visible when it should and hide when it should be not visible.

Comment: wouldn't that happen automatically when the activity changes?